# Center div with background image in page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center a div, and it's content in the center of the page. The div has a background image.

This is my attempt with `Flexbox`:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .flex_container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .inner {
            height: 788px;
            width: 1400px;
            background-image: url('matrix_bg.png');
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<div class="flex_container">
   <div class="inner">
      <div style="margin-top: 100px;"> Some text in the center </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the result is like this:
[image]

As you can see, the inner text appears centered in the page - this is what I want, but I also would want the background image also to be centered.

Any suggestions?

---

**Update: I tried a few suggestions, but this does not give the desired effect**:

with `background-position: center;`: this one seems fine, except only a portion of the image is shown. I would like the image to scale to fit within the bounds of the parent `div`.
[image]

with `background-size: cover`: this would have been perfect, except the image is still not centered.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div is already in the center. Since the width of **div** is larger than image and you used **background-size:contain**, so it's not appearing as it should be.

You can use:

```
background-position: center;
```

or

```
background-size:cover;
```

Else you can also reduce the width of your inner div.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .flex_container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .inner {
            height:300px;
            width: 400px;

            background-image: url('https://effortcatalyst.online/matrix_bg.png');
            
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex_container">
     <div class="inner">
        <h1> Some text in the center </h1>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See my updated answer, I tried your suggestion but this still does not give the desired result.

Comment: Try running the above code snippet. This time I've used an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `background-position: center;` property to center the image.

Updated Answer:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .flex_container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .inner {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;

            background-image: url('https://effortcatalyst.online/matrix_bg.png');

            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex_container">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1> Some text in the center </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See my updated answer, I tried your suggestion but this still does not give the desired result.

Comment: The issue is that your div  is taking only the space which you set for .inner class. I have updated my answer in which I used 100vh and 100vw for full height and width, like you wanted